# php spreadsheets Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: excel, codeigniter, spreadsheet

I have installed phpspreadsheets with composer using command line(back to medieval era..). Now, I have some errors after I have included the phpspreadsheets  library in my project:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in ..../application/libraries/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Engine/Logger.php on line 93

So, in Logger.php on line 93 the code is:

```
public function writeDebugLog(...$args)
```

Has anyone dealt with such issue ? it's so annoying, it took forever to install composer and run install stpreadsheets from command line and now this error...(and the fact that I have to use command line it's killing me)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? What version does the library you installed require?

Answer (score 0):

The library you installed probably depends on 5.6 or newer and you probably have an older version. The `...` operator was added in PHP 5.6 so if you are on an older version it should be a syntax error. See [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) for docs.